# FFMPEG desktop capture randomly stops streaming to RTMP endpoint. Why?

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, streaming, cpu-usage, rtmp

I am using the following FFMPEG command for desktop streaming to an RTMP endpoint:

```
ffmpeg.exe -report -fflags nobuffer -framerate 30 -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -f gdigrab -thread_queue_size 256 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 136 -video_size 1280x720 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 1000k -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 60 -f flv -movflags faststart -crf 23 rtmp://75cw3w9g:czol1pao@1cb45c.entrypoint.cloud.wowza.com/app-D2TFw12x/dCs4YjV5 -f dshow -rtbufsize 200M -thread_queue_size 1024 -i "audio=CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)"
```

Operating System is Windows 10.

The command works as expected, however, unpredictably, CPU usage and frame rate drop to very low levels, and the stream to RTMP clearly cuts out.
Below is an example of what happens:

```
ffmpeg started on 2022-01-14 at 21:32:42
Report written to "ffmpeg-20220114-213242.log"
Log level: 48
ffmpeg version 2021-06-23-git-947122f111-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.3.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavcodec     59.  1.102 / 59.  1.102
  libavformat    59.  3.101 / 59.  3.101
  libavdevice    59.  0.100 / 59.  0.100
  libavfilter     8.  0.102 /  8.  0.102
  libswscale      6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
[gdigrab @ 000002547ea616c0] Capturing whole desktop as 1280x720x32 at (0,136)
[gdigrab @ 000002547ea616c0] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, gdigrab, from 'desktop':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1642195962.552738, bitrate: 884748 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, bgra, 1280x720, 884748 kb/s, 30 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, dshow, from 'audio=CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1569.872000, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
  Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
[rtmp @ 000002540239b540] Ignoring unsupported var reason
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (bmp (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000002547ead5fc0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2 AVX512
[libx264 @ 000002547ead5fc0] profile High, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000002547ead5fc0] 264 - core 164 r3065 ae03d92 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=60 keyint_min=6 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://75cw3w9g:czol1pao@1cb45c.entrypoint.cloud.wowza.com/app-D2TFw12x/dCs4YjV5':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.3.101
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1280x720, q=2-31, 1000 kb/s, 30 fps, 1k tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.1.102 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/1000000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.1.102 aac
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.44 bitrate=   7.4kbits/s speed=9.33x    
frame=   17 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.44 bitrate=   7.4kbits/s speed=0.798x    
frame=   32 fps= 30 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.44 bitrate=   7.4kbits/s speed=0.413x    
frame=   46 fps= 29 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.44 bitrate=   7.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.281x    
frame=   57 fps= 28 q=29.0 size=      40kB time=00:00:02.63 bitrate= 124.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=1.27x    
frame=   64 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=     135kB time=00:00:02.96 bitrate= 374.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=1.12x    
frame=   76 fps= 23 q=29.0 size=     179kB time=00:00:03.44 bitrate= 425.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=1.05x    
frame=   82 fps= 22 q=29.0 size=     209kB time=00:00:03.96 bitrate= 432.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=1.04x    
frame=   85 fps= 18 q=29.0 size=     227kB time=00:00:03.96 bitrate= 470.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.861x    
frame=   87 fps= 16 q=29.0 size=     247kB time=00:00:03.96 bitrate= 510.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.741x    
frame=   92 fps= 16 q=29.0 size=     279kB time=00:00:03.96 bitrate= 576.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.676x    
frame=   94 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=     300kB time=00:00:03.96 bitrate= 620.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.608x    
frame=  104 fps= 15 q=29.0 size=     335kB time=00:00:04.44 bitrate= 616.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.632x    
frame=  108 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=     353kB time=00:00:04.44 bitrate= 649.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.585x    
frame=  114 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=     382kB time=00:00:04.95 bitrate= 630.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.601x    
frame=  118 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=     475kB time=00:00:04.95 bitrate= 784.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.433x    
frame=  124 fps=9.6 q=29.0 size=     490kB time=00:00:04.95 bitrate= 809.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.385x    
frame=  134 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=     525kB time=00:00:05.44 bitrate= 790.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.407x    
[gdigrab @ 000002547ea616c0] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 256)
frame=  143 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=     560kB time=00:00:05.95 bitrate= 770.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.416x    
frame=  150 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=     591kB time=00:00:05.95 bitrate= 812.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.402x    
frame=  156 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=     615kB time=00:00:06.44 bitrate= 781.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.42x    
frame=  162 fps= 10 q=27.0 size=     665kB time=00:00:06.44 bitrate= 845.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.399x    
frame=  167 fps=9.9 q=29.0 size=     686kB time=00:00:06.44 bitrate= 872.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.384x    
frame=  169 fps=9.6 q=29.0 size=     701kB time=00:00:06.95 bitrate= 826.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.396x    
frame=  171 fps=9.2 q=29.0 size=     721kB time=00:00:06.95 bitrate= 849.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.373x    
frame=  173 fps=8.8 q=29.0 size=     730kB time=00:00:06.95 bitrate= 860.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.356x    
frame=  178 fps=8.1 q=29.0 size=     821kB time=00:00:06.95 bitrate= 967.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.316x
```

In this case, the problem occurred right after starting ffmpeg. In most cases this happens after a time interval so variable that it is difficult to identify any pattern.
For example, it can all go smoothly (at constant 30 fps) for 1 hour and then all of a sudden the CPU usage and frame rate drop to very low levels, and the stream to RTMP clearly cuts out.
I can provide any other information you may need.

Is there anyone who could give me some advice or suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have the `-f dshow -rtbufsize 200M -thread_queue_size 1024 -i "audio=CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)"` part at the end? Does the problem reproduced without this part? (Does the problem reproduced with video only, without the audio?)

Comment: The capture is done inside a VM via an rdp session and the use of that audio device, is the only way I have to be able to also capture the audio along with the video. In fact I have never tried without capturing audio, I will try as soon as possible, thanks.